# How to keep my board in the center for different screen size in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, android, windows, unity-game-engine

I am developing a board game. My board is created dynamically using C# script like so

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws the board of the figure. Call the Load event of the form.
    /// </summary>
    public void DrawingBoard()
    {    
        CubeDark.transform.localScale = new Vector3(3f,2f,3f);      
        CubeLight.transform.localScale =  new Vector3(3f,2f,3f);
        for(int i = 0; i < _boardSize; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < _boardSize; j++)
            {
                if((i+j)%2 == 0)
                {
                    UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(CubeDark,new Vector3(i*3,_boardHeight,j*3), Quaternion.identity);    
                }
                else
                {
                    UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(CubeLight,new Vector3(i*3,_boardHeight,j*3), Quaternion.identity);
                }
            }
        }           
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

What I want to do now is to scale the camera in order to put the board in the center of the screen ( no matter what size of screen ).

What I have tried so far is to attach the below script to my camera GameObject.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PositionCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public float fWidth = 2.0f; // Desired width
    void Start () {
        float xFactor = Screen.width / 1024f;
        float yFactor = Screen.height  / 768f;          
        Camera.main.rect=new Rect(0,0,1,xFactor/yFactor);

    }
}
```

But unfortunately, it didn't work. A part of the board still does not appear.

So here come my questions:

- How can i keep my board centered for different screen resolution and for different platforms ( android and standalone )?
- How can i make my game window resizable when building my unity project?
- For android platform, Why does only half of the screen show the game?
  [image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the center of your DrawingBoard is not in the center of the coordinate system (0,0,0).

I think you should instantiate from -size/2 to +size/2, not from 0 to size:

```
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(CubeLight,new Vector3(i*3-_boardSize/2,_boardHeight,j*3-_boardSize/2), Quaternion.identity);
```

If you do that, the board will always be in the center of the coordinate system, so it will always be in the center of the screen, at any resolution (if your camera is looking at the center of the screen - you should check the position and rotation of the camera to make sure).

Also, it is important where is the center of your CubeLight and CubeDark. It should be in the middle of the cube.

For resizing and resolution, check the settings in Unity Editor under "Edit / Project settings / Player / Resolution and presentation"